# Remove layers references from geoprocessing tool

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

When I run my tool it is calling some geoprocessing tools and performing some operations on some layers but when i delete those layers from arcmap then those layers are removed from arcmap but not from Geoprocessing tool. Please tell me how to remove layers references from geoprocessing tools programmatically.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange.  If you want an answer for your question, you will have to go into more detail about your issue.  Please edit your question to include details about what tool you are using and what you mean when you say you want to remove the layer references from your geoprocessing tool.  Also, you may want to include some code and link to a screenshot.  You may want to use imgur.com as an image host until you have enough reputation to post images.

Comment: @Manish Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Which version you are using for ArcGIS (9.x or 10.x)

Comment: I'm not sure why people think it is unclear. Anyone who has used a gp tool within ArcMap, has seen the Layer being available as a input in the dialog box of the gp tool. I'm 100% certain that the user is referring to it. I'm voting to keep it open.

Comment: I think it is unclear - is your tool a model or a Python script tool?  Where are you seeing the layer references that you want to remove programmatically?